# Regex in if else statement in R

Tags: r, regex, if-statement

I have a rather simple question. I am trying to get the if else statement below to work.

It is supposed to assign '1' if the if statement is met, 0 otherwise. 
My problem is that I cannot get the regex in the if statement to work ('\w*|\W*). It is supposed to specify the condition that the string either is "Registration Required" or Registration required followed by any character. I cannot specify the exact cases, because following the "Registration required" (in the cases where something follows), it will usually be a date (varying for each observation) and a few words.

```
Registration_cleaned <- c()

for (i in 1:length(Registration)) {
  if (Registration[i] == ' Registration Required\\w*|\\W*') {
    Meta_Registration_cleaned <- 1
  } else {
    Meta_Registration_cleaned <- 0 
  }

 Registration_cleaned <- c(Registration_cleaned, Meta_Registration_cleaned)

}
```

Comment: With `stringr`, you may check if a string starts with `Registration Required` using `if (str_detect(Registration[i], "(?i)^Registration Required"))...` (`(?i)` makes it case insensitive). If you do not care about the chars after, why match them at all?

Comment: `==` does not work with regular expressions.

Comment: ... why not use "$" to lookup if the string *ends* with "Registration required"... ?

Comment: also... why the for loop? Is not simply `baseR::ifelse()` or `dplyr::if_else` the better choice?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a short test vector `Registration`.

Comment: You can avoid the whole loop, as regex functions are vectorized and logicals can be coerced to 1 or 0, so `Registration_cleaned <- as.integer(grepl('registration required', Registration, ignore.case = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

You may use transform together with ifelse function to set the Meta_Registration_cleaned.
For matching the regular expression grep function can be used with pattern "Registration Required\w*".

```
Registration <- data.frame(reg = c("Registration Required", "Registration Required ddfdqf","some str", "Regixxstration Required ddfdqf"),stringsAsFactors = F)

transform(Registration,Meta_Registration_cleaned = ifelse(grepl("Registration Required\\w*",Registration[,"reg"]), 1, 0))
```

Gives result:

```
                      reg Meta_Registration_cleaned
1          Registration Required                         1
2   Registration Required ddfdqf                         1
3                       some str                         0
4 Regixxstration Required ddfdqf                         0
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood the OP completely, because I have understood the question entirely differently than anyone else here.

My comment earlier suggested looking for the regex at the *end* of the string.

```
Registration <- data.frame(reg = c("Registration Required", "Registration Required ddfdqf","Registration Required 10/12/2000"),stringsAsFactors = F)

#thanks @user1653941 for drafting the sample vector

Registration$Meta_Registration_cleaned <- grepl('Registration required$', Registration$reg, ignore.case = TRUE)

Registration

1            Registration Required                      TRUE
2     Registration Required ddfdqf                     FALSE
3 Registration Required 10/12/2000                     FALSE
```

I understand the OP as such that the condition is: Either the string "Registration required" without following characters, or... anything else. Looking forward to the OPs comment.